# Ionic backbutton after navbutton

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I need to show   `<ion-nav-buttons>`   before  `<ion-nav-back-button>`  in my ionic applications header,i put back button after nav button like as bellow in my header.but nav button always show after back button.How to fix this?

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
   <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
 </button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>

 <ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-back-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);`

put it in your controller.